# Laravel Homestead - How to edit homestead.rb when virtualbox not running?

Tags: laravel-4, virtualbox, homestead

I attempted the top answer on this thread:

[Vagrant port forwarding 80 to 8000 with Laravel Homestead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492901/vagrant-port-forwarding-80-to-8000-with-laravel-homestead)

which was to make this change in the homestead.rb file:

> config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8000 to
>   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80

I am running a newer version of homestead (not sure where to find the exact version), on a mac.

It did not work, when attempting to start up my homestead virtualbox it now says:

> Vagrant cannot forward the specified ports on this VM, since they
>   would collide with some other application that is already listening on
>   these ports. The forwarded port to 80 is already in use on the host
>   machine.

I had edited the homestead.rb file via ssh and vim while the homestead virtualbox was running, but now I can't get it to run and I can't figure out how to undo my changes.

Help with both of these would be greatly appreciated!

1. How to edit the homestead.rb file when the virtualbox is not running? I believe it is inside either VirtualBox VMs/homestead/homestead.vbox or box-disk1.vmdk, but I do not know how to access inside them.
2. Help with getting the port to forward correctly to 80 since the solution from the other question did not work.

Comment: @noeldiaz since it was your answer from the other question, if you could help that would be awesome.

Comment: Sure man.  Ok, first thing, if you want to know where the homestead 2.+ files are, they are inside the .composer directory in your profile.  So for me they are in:
/Users/noel/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts

Now, you are sure you want to run on 80?  Running on another not an option?  Then it probably is your built in apache server on your mac or something else is grabbing that port 80.  Do you maybe have another VM, or MAMP, or anything like that?

If it is the built in apache server, try:
apachectl stop
To see if it stops running and releases 80.

Comment: Here is a link to some instructions to find out what might be using port 80 is you can't figure it out:
http://www.mkyong.com/mac/mac-osx-what-program-is-using-port-80/

Basically run:

sudo lsof -i :80

And check the resulting list for clues on what it could be.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly! I was able to revert things back, thank you for pointing me to those files.

Comment: I killed my local apache server to free up Port 80 and the virtualbox did actually boot up, but my site would not work with just the ip as you had mentioned in your answer on the previous question. I went to the ip address that was specified in my homestead.yaml file, but it would not work. Feel free to add your answers from your comments as an actual answer so I can give you credit for the help. I will start up another question for what I am actually trying to accomplish -> test a facebook app on my application (but having to include the port: 8000 does not work with the fb app api.

Comment: My homestead.rb file has the private network set to 192.168.10.10, but when I try to set my homestead.yaml file to 192.168.10.10 it says: "The specified host network collides with a non-host only network!
This will cause your specified IP to be inaccessible. Please change
the IP or name of your host only network so that it no longer matches that of a bridged or non-host only network." So I have my homestead.yaml ip set to 192.168.56.1 and then it works with the port forwarding to 8000, but not if I set the host to 80.

Comment: @noeldiaz - Nevermind, got it all figured out!! I was just having ip address conflicts, changed both the homestead.rb private network and the homestead.yaml to 192.168.56.1 and made the change of the host to 80, and it finally works!! Add those things from above as an actual answer so I can vote it as a correct answer so you get credit. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem!  Glad it all worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homestead 2.+ stores it's files inside your .composer directory inside your User directory.  For example, for me it is in:

```
/Users/noel/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead
```

You will find all the configuration and script files that used to reside in the older Homestead 1.0 directories.

Now, since something is holding on to your port 80, it probably means that your local apache installation is running.  You can test to see what is holding on to the port by running:

```
sudo lsof -i :80
```

To list all processes listening on port 80 (incoming and outgoing).

To stop the local apache you can run:

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

That should release the port for you to use with your virtual machine.