# Laravel homestead: setup each site on different port

Tags: vagrant, homestead, laravel-5.1

By default homestead redirects port 8000 to 80 so I access each site like this: sitename.app:8000.

How can I setup each site on a different port?

The reason I want this is to use vagrant share but this "shares" the first site it finds and the only solution I found is to have different ports.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492901/vagrant-port-forwarding-80-to-8000-with-laravel-homestead

Comment: @MiharbiHernandez That doesn't answer my question, I want each site on different port, e.g.

site1.app:8001
site2.app:8002

Comment: Have you got somewhere with setting a different port?

Comment: No, I just renamed the sitename to start with "aa" because vagrant share take the first site

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. I you want to map another app to a different port. You need to create a different homestead box for it.